# Changing the order of an array to be the same as another array SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift

I've seen this has been done before but can't seem to find it in `swift`. So I have two arrays, `arrayA` and `arrayB`. I want `arrayB` to sort itself into the same order a `arrayA`. So for example her is the arrays:

```
var arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5]
var arrayB = [4,5,1,2,3]
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to sort with increase and with decrease?

Comment: I want arrayB to become arrayA, they have the same elements inside. but arrayB is in the wrong order

Comment: you need to make sort `arrayB` using simple sorting algorithms such as "Insertion", "Selection", and others.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: just use this documentation about [sorting algorithms](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com)

Comment: There was a reason I asked the question, so I could find the answer quickly and efficiently. Not to have to learn algorithms.

Comment: If you want them to be the same, why not just copy? arrayA = arrayB?

Comment: In what sense? This question is obviously a much simpler form of what I want to achieve.

Comment: @RomanSausarnes, thought the same. But maybe those elements are classes with different values and he wants to sort them based on a certain value?

Comment: @HenryBrown: *"This question is obviously a much simpler form of what I want to achieve"* – Then why don't you show a non-trivial example that shows what you want to achieve?

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me, but this *might* be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432656/how-can-i-sort-multiple-arrays-based-on-the-sorted-order-of-another-array.

Comment: arrayA and arrayB both have the same elements, I simply want to change the order of arrayB to become in the same order as arrayA. There must be a method or something for doing this??

Comment: @HenryBrown: If they have the same elements then you can simply assign `arrayB = arrayA`.

Comment: This question takes the prize as the most unclear or unnecessary ever asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) This is what I understand**

arrayA defines some kind of order. In your example it is coincidentally the ascending order of integers but it can really be any kind of order like one of the following:

1. Example 1: [5, 4, 1, 3, 2] Ascending by number "names" (*five, four, one, three, two*)
2. Example 2: [5, 2, 4, 3, 1]: Ascending by italian names of numbers (*cinque, due, quattro, tre, uno*)

**2) You don't like this kind of solution**

```
arrayB = arrayA
```

You actually need a way to **move** the elements inside arrayB in order to make it sorted as arrayA (maybe because you need a solution for a more generic problem where the elements of the arrays are not simply integers).

**3) Now, my solution**

```
var arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var arrayB = [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

var indexes = [Int: Int]()
for (index, elm) in enumerate(arrayA)  {
    indexes[elm] = index
}

// now indexes[i] gives me the position of the integer i inside arrayA, e.g. indexes[3] -> 2

arrayB.sort { return indexes[$0] < indexes[$1] }

// now arrayB has been sorted as arrayA
```

**Conclusion**

This approach does work when:

1. there are not duplicates in arrayA (or arrayB)
2. arrayA.count == arrayB.count
3. arrayA and arrayB contain the same elements

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes! Perfect! Thank you exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to use the `reverse()` function.

```
var arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5]

arrayB = reverse(arrayA)
```

will result in `arrayB = [5,4,3,2,1]` and vice versa.