# Filter Array based on the Filtering of Another Array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Say I had two arrays:

```
var arrayA = ["Yes", "Yes2", "Not Answered", "No"]
var arrayB = ["Yes", "NA", "Yes2", "NA"]
```

And I wanted to remove the "NA"s from arrayB by doing:

```
var filtered = arrayB.filter({$0 != "NA"})
```

How could I remove the items at the same indexes removed in arrayA. I thought about using the find() function, but that only returns the first index a string appears. You can remove overlap from the arrays by:

```
let res = arrayA.filter { !contains(arrayB, $0) }
```

but how could I filter an array based on the filtering of another array?

the result would have:

```
arrayBFiltered = ["Yes", "Yes2"]
arrayAFiltered = ["Yes", "Not Answered"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have accepted the answer I would consider the least "swift" way and the hackiest way. @Matteo's method is much nicer and much more "swifty". I do wonder why you don't have a data model to hold these data though? If they are so closely related then you should have them in a single model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might prefer using `zip`:

```
var arrayA = ["Yes", "Yes2", "Not Answered", "No"]
var arrayB = ["Yes", "NA", "Yes2", "NA"]

let result = filter(zip(arrayA, arrayB)) { (a, b) in b != "NA" }

for (a, b) in result {
    println("A: \(a) -> B: \(b)")
}
```

**EDIT: SWIFT 2.0**

In Swift 2.0 it will be even easier to obtain an array of a consolidated ad-hod `struct` (say ... `Foo`) for clearer subsequent code:

```
struct Foo {
    let a: String
    let b: String
}
// Foo.init will be the function automatically generated by the default initialiser

let result = zip(arrayA, arrayB)
    .filter { (a, b) in b != "NA" }
    .map(Foo.init)
// Order of a and b is important

// result is an Array<Foo> suitable for a clearer subsequent code
for item in result {
    print("A: \(item.a) -> B: \(item.b)")
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is what I was coming back to write. This is the "swift" way of doing this. Although, I question why the OP hasn't created an object to hold these related data?

Comment: @Fogmeister As an exercice I added a Swift 2.0 variant ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The ideas from [How can I sort multiple arrays based on the sorted order of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432656/how-can-i-sort-multiple-arrays-based-on-the-sorted-order-of-another-array) could
be used here, that would work for two or more arrays:

```
let arrayA = ["Yes", "Yes2", "Not Answered", "No"]
let arrayB = ["Yes", "NA", "Yes2", "NA"]

// Determine array indices that should be kept:
let indices = map(filter(enumerate(arrayB), { $1 != "NA" } ), { $0.0 } )

// Filter arrays based on the indices:
let arrayAFiltered = Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: arrayA, indices: indices))
let arrayBFiltered = Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: arrayB, indices: indices))

println(arrayAFiltered) // [Yes, Not Answered]
println(arrayBFiltered) // [Yes, Yes2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to make the remove code directly inside the `filter` closure:

```
// both are vars so you can mutate them directly
var arrayA = ["Yes", "Yes2", "Not Answered", "No"]
var arrayB = ["Yes", "NA", "Yes2", "NA"]

arrayA = filter(enumerate(arrayA)){
    arrayB.removeAtIndex($0)
    return $1 != "Na"
}

// use filtered arrayA and arrayB
```