# Randomize two arrays the same way Swift

Tags: swift

I know there is a new shuffle method with **iOS 9**
but I am wondering if there is anyway to shuffle two arrays the same way?

For example

```
[1,2,3,4] and [a,b,c,d]
shuffle
[3,4,1,2] and [c,d,a,b]
```

Comment: Which new shuffle method in iOS 9 are you referring to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `shuffle()` method from [How do I shuffle an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift) and the ideas from [How can I sort multiple arrays based on the sorted order of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432656/how-can-i-sort-multiple-arrays-based-on-the-sorted-order-of-another-array)
you can shuffle the array *indices* and then re-order both (or more)
arrays accordingly:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

var shuffled_indices = a.indices.shuffle()

let shuffled_a = Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: a, indices: shuffled_indices))
let shuffled_b = Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: b, indices: shuffled_indices))

print(shuffled_a) // [3, 1, 2, 4]
print(shuffled_b) // ["c", "a", "b", "d"]
```

---

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8):** `PermutationGenerator` does not
exist in Swift 3 anymore.
Using the `shuffled()` method
from [Shuffle array swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843647/shuffle-array-swift-3/37843901#37843901) the same can be achieved with

```
var shuffled_indices = a.indices.shuffled()

let shuffled_a = shuffled_indices.map { a[$0] }
let shuffled_b = shuffled_indices.map { b[$0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store the values temporarily, shuffle the keys and then rebuild the other array by extracting the values from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any built-in shuffle mechanism in Swift 2.0.  Assuming this doesn't exist, I borrowed some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift).

```
extension CollectionType where Index == Int {
    /// Return a copy of `self` with its elements shuffled
    func shuffle() -> [Generator.Element] {
        var list = Array(self)
        list.shuffleInPlace()
        return list
    }
}

extension MutableCollectionType where Index == Int {
    /// Shuffle the elements of `self` in-place.
    mutating func shuffleInPlace() {
        // empty and single-element collections don't shuffle
        if count < 2 { return }

        for i in 0..<count - 1 {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
            guard i != j else { continue }
            swap(&self[i], &self[j])
        }
    }
}

let shuffleOrder = [0,1,2,3]
let shuffled = shuffleOrder.shuffle()


var newArray1 = [String]()
var newArray2 = [String]()

let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let array2 = ["w", "x", "y", "z"]


shuffled.forEach() { index in
    newArray1.append(array1[index])
    newArray2.append(array2[index])
}
```

This solves the problem in a really straight forward way.  It creates an array, `shuffleOrder`, that just has an index for each possible index in the starting arrays.  It then shuffles these indices to create a random sampling order.  Finally, it constructs two new arrays, based off of the starting arrays, sampling them with the `shuffled` values.  While this doesn't mutate the original 2 arrays in place, it would be simple to modify this to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon Martin R's original answer, you could approach the problem using GameKit.

The answer is written in Swift4:

```
var arrayA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var arrayB = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

//Get The Indices Of The 1st Array 
var shuffledIndices: [Int] = Array(arrayA.indices)
print("Shuffled Indices = \(shuffledIndices)")

//Shuffle These Using GameKit
shuffledIndices = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: shuffledIndices) as! [Int]

//Map The Objects To The Shuffled Indices
arrayA = shuffledIndices.map { arrayA[$0] }
arrayB = shuffledIndices.map { arrayB[$0] }

//Log The Results
print("""
Array A = \(arrayA)
Array B = \(arrayB)
""")
```

Hope it helps ^_________^.