# How do I shuffle multiple arrays using the same new indexes for each?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of book titles, and another with corresponding book authors. Let's just assume I need them in separate arrays as opposed to the same dictionary. How can I reorder the indexes of both arrays, while making sure the index of array 2 still corresponds to the index of array 1?

```
//This is what I currently have:
var arrayOne = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
var arrayTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4]

//The new indexes should be random, non-repeating integers
arrayOne = ["four", "two", "three", "one"]
arrayTwo = [4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show some code you have written so far to solve this problem

Comment: @SunilChauhan because I want the new order to be random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code is tested on Swift 2.0

```
    extension CollectionType {
    /// Return a copy of `self` with its elements shuffled
    func shuffle() -> [Generator.Element] {
        var list = Array(self)
        list.shuffleInPlace()
        return list
    }
}

extension MutableCollectionType where Index == Int {
    /// Shuffle the elements of `self` in-place.
    mutating func shuffleInPlace() {
        // empty and single-element collections don't shuffle
        if count < 2 { return }

        for i in 0..<count - 1 {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
            guard i != j else { continue }
            swap(&self[i], &self[j])
        }
    }
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

var shuffled_ind = arr1.indices.shuffle()

let shuffled_arr1 = Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: arr1, indices: shuffled_ind))
let shuffled_arr2 = Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: arr2, indices: shuffled_ind))

print(shuffled_arr1) // [3, 1, 2, 4]
print(shuffled_arr2) // ["c", "a", "b", "d"]
```

> HERE IS THE OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT]

Took Reference from this two post and used their extention

[How do I shuffle an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift)

[How can I sort multiple arrays based on the sorted order of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432656/how-can-i-sort-multiple-arrays-based-on-the-sorted-order-of-another-array)[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift)

[Randomize two arrays the same way Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726962/randomize-two-arrays-the-same-way-swift)

Comment: `indices` has no member named `shuffle()`?

Comment: And I also don't want to sort. I want the new indexes to be random, non-repeating integers

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED THE CODE AND IS RANDOM

Comment: if you find my answer usefull don't forget to upvote and accept :)