# Int and Self.Index.Distance conflict in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I have:

```
extension MutableCollection where Index == Int { // shuffle elements of self in place

    mutating func shuffleInPlace() {

        if count < 2 { return } // empty and single-element collections don't shuffle

        for i in 0 ..< count - 1 {
            let j = Int( arc4random_uniform( UInt32( count - i ) ) ) + i
            guard i != j else { continue }
            swap( &self[ i ], &self[ j ] )
            ...

...
```

and I'm getting the error:

> Binary operator Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Self.IndexDistance'

Does anyone know how to rectify this?

Comment: Dave answered this and then his answer disappeared! It was to wrap count - 1 in parentheses: ( count - 1 ), which I verified and it works. Thanks, Dave, sorry I couldn't upvote your answer :(

Comment: I think you may have the answer here: `Int( arc4random_uniform( UInt32( count - 1 ) ) )` Sounds like count - 1 needs to be of type Int. Yea I deleted because I realized I didn't know the type of count =p and whether my answer helped change it's type. I undeleted...

Comment: If your code comes from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/2976878), then note that it has been updated with a Swift 3 version.

Comment: That [answer above ( the duplicate )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843647/shuffle-array-swift-3) is far superior as it takes into account array slices, and should be used instead.

Comment: @DaveThomas: I have linked to that one because it is the identical question. Nate Cook added a Swift 3 version to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/1187415 later, and that should work for slices as well, and even for collections which are not indexed by `Int`.

Comment: @MartinR Beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, wrap `count -1` in parenthesis :

```
for i in 0 ..< (count - 1)
```