# Shuffle Array Binary Operator Error

Tags: arrays, swift3, shuffle

I looked at a similar problem in the Shuffle Array Swift 3 post and tried the code from the Answer, but I still get the same error on the same line.

```
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(countArray - i))) + i
```

The line above throws the error:

Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'C.IndexDistance' and 'Range C.IndexDistance'

Entire function:

```
//function used to shuffle imageArray
func shuffle<C: MutableCollection>(_ imageArray: C) -> C where C.Index == Int {
    var imageArray = imageArray
    var countArray = imageArray.count

    for i in [1 ..< countArray] {
        countArray = imageArray.count
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(countArray - i))) + i
        swap(&imageArray[i], &imageArray[j])
    }
    return imageArray
}
```

Revised Code (below) Still Returns Same Error:

Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'C.IndexDistance' and 'Range C.IndexDistance'

```
//function used to shuffle imageArray
func shuffle<C: MutableCollection>(_ imageArray: C) -> C where C.Index == Int {
    var imageArray = imageArray
    var countArray = imageArray.count
    for i in imageArray.startIndex ..< imageArray.endIndex-1 {
        countArray = imageArray.count
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(countArray - i))) + i
        swap(&imageArray[i], &imageArray[j])
    }
    return imageArray
}
```

Comment: Well... what's the error?

Comment: "Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'C.IndexDistance' and 'Range C.IndexDistance'

Comment: Oh yeah, that's an annoying one. `MutableCollection` doesn't require `Index` to be an `Int`, it keeps it as an abstract type. I can try taking a look at this tomorrow if it isn't answered already.

Comment: Duplicate of [Shuffle array swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843647/shuffle-array-swift-3): Replace `1` by `imageArray.startIndex+1` and `countArray` by `imageArray.endIndex`.

Comment: Actually it should be `for i in imageArray.startIndex ..< imageArray.endIndex-1`, your version would never move the *first* array element.

Comment: Martin R., I revised the code per your comment (and posted it above) but it still returns the same error. Also, I read the Shuffle Array Swift post several times trying to apply the solution, no luck yet.  The line that returns the error is:   let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(countArray - i))) + i

Comment: @JimmyMaguire: You did not replace *all* instances of `countArray` by `imageArray.endIndex`... It will compile and run if you do, I tested it.

Comment: @MartinR yes, that worked, thank you very much