# Swift 3 - Cannot assign type () to Array when using shuffle extension

Tags: arrays, swift, shuffle

I am attempting to shuffle an array using an shuffle extension.  However the compiler is complaining it

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[EYPlayer]'

```
class SomeClass {
    var playerOrder: Array = [EYPlayer]()

    public func shufflePlayerOrder() {
        self.playerOrder = self.playerOrder.shuffle()
    }
}
```

The shuffle extension looks like:

```
extension MutableCollection where Index == Int {
    /// Shuffle the elements of `self` in-place.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        // empty and single-element collections don't shuffle
        if count < 2 { return }

        for i in startIndex ..< endIndex - 1 {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(endIndex - i))) + i
            if i != j {
                swap(&self[i], &self[j])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe its asking me to cast the array but I am not sure.

What is the main issue here?

Thanks

Comment: Your `shuffle` method mutates the array in-place and doesn't return anything. Just remove `self.playerOrder = `

Comment: Ah, many thanks!! I perhaps was expecting it be returning when it wasn't. Many thanks -- accepted your answer

Comment: Why are you erasing type of content in `playerOrder`?

Comment: That code looks familiar http://stackoverflow.com/a/37843901/1187415 :)

Comment: Yes, I am using your code on that.

Comment: I don't understand. I'd like to shuffle the order of self.playerOrder.  I do not see where it is erasing it.