# Why does count return different types for Collection vs. Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, collections, count, associated-types

When I'm extending `Collection` the type of `count` is `IndexDistance`.

When I'm extending `Array` type the `count` is of type `Int`

Why is there such a distinction? Is this a recent change or it's always been like this?

I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37843901/5175709) but couldn't pick up much.

The only thing I deemed related, but didn't understand was:

> Another advantage is that this[IndexDistance] also works correctly
>   with array slices (where the index of the first element is not
>   necessarily zero

Not sure what that means.

The reason I'm asking is that why does the code throw an error on Collection but doesn't do such on Array...even though both `count`s are ultimately an `Int`.

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable{
    func whatever(){
        for index in 0...count{ //  binary operator '...' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Self.IndexDistance'

        }
    }
}

extension Array where Element: Comparable{
    func whatever(){
        for index in 0...count{ // NO ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Based on comments made by Martin and others, I've added an extra question. Likely this is the root cause of my question...

Does it mean that within `Collection` type the `IndexDistance` **isn't** defined to `Int`. Basically in general at the 'Protocol' level associatedTypes **aren't defined**...It's waiting for a *concrete* type to do that? Is that right?

That being said is there any meaningful use case for accessing `count` at the 'Protocol' level? I mean you can't compare it against any `Int` so it seems pretty useless.

Comment: `IndexDistance` for `Array` is `Int`. `IndexDistance` is associated type.

Comment: Have you checked this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/indexdistance

Comment: Note that `IndexDistance` is going away (being replaced by `Int`) in Swift 4.1: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0191-eliminate-indexdistance.md

Comment: @AamirR 1. it's deprecated. 2. Not sure why even though it's an `Int` it doesn't work e.g. `binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Self.IndexDistance'
        for index in 1..<count{`

Comment: @user28434 correctly explained it. `Collection` is a protocol with an associated type `IndexDistance`. `Array` is a concrete type, conforming to `Collection`, and defining `IndexDistance = Int`. Actually *all* concrete types in the Swift library define `IndexDistance = Int`, and that is why it is going away in Swift 4.1, as Hamish said.

Comment: @MartinR isn't that when you typeAlias...you can call the exact same functions of the same type? why can't the `...` be applied between 2 `Int`s ? Is it by design or language limitation?

Comment: `...` can be applied between two `Int`s, that's why your array extension compiles.  The one in `Collection` doesn't compile because `count` isn't an `Int`, it's the associated type `IndexDistance` which (before swift 4.1) can be any `SignedInteger` type

Comment: Up to Swift 4.0, `IndexDistance` is an *associated type* of the Collection Protocol, not a type alias. Theoretically you could define a collection type with a non-Int IndexDistance. In Swift 4.1 it is defined as a type alias, only for backward compatibility.

Comment: @dan my Swift version is `4.0.2`. I command clicked on `Collection` and then I see: `public protocol Collection : Sequence {

    /// A type that represents the number of steps between a pair of
    /// indices.
    associatedtype IndexDistance = Int` Doesn't the last line mean it's actually an `Int`? hence the static compiler shouldn't throw that error.

Comment: @MartinR My bad. So after `4.1` this error would no longer happen on Collections?

Comment: @Honey: No, `associatedtype IndexDistance = Int` means that the *default type* is `Int`. – And yes, your first example compiles with Swift 4.1.

Comment: I somewhat get it. If defaulting it doesn't work then what would work? You said *all concrete types in the Swift library define IndexDistance = Int* HOW exactly? I see that for Array type it's written as: `public typealias Index = Int`. The only difference is that in Collection it says `IndexDistance` instead of `Index`

Comment: @MartinR I read more on this. Made an edit...sorry for constant comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Associated Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189) in the Swift Programming Language (emphasis added):

> When defining a protocol, it’s sometimes useful to declare one or more associated types as part of the protocol’s definition. An associated type gives a **placeholder name** to a type that is used as part of the protocol. **The actual type to use for that associated type isn’t specified until the protocol is adopted.** Associated types are specified with the associatedtype keyword.

In **Swift 3/4.0,** the `Collection` protocol defines five associated types
(from [What’s in a Collection?](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/collection-associated-types/)):

```
protocol Collection: Indexable, Sequence {
    associatedtype Iterator: IteratorProtocol = IndexingIterator<Self>
    associatedtype SubSequence: IndexableBase, Sequence = Slice<Self>
    associatedtype Index: Comparable // declared in IndexableBase
    associatedtype IndexDistance: SignedInteger = Int
    associatedtype Indices: IndexableBase, Sequence = DefaultIndices<Self>
    ...
}
```

Here

```
    associatedtype IndexDistance: SignedInteger = Int
```

is an associated type declaration with a type constraint (`: SignedInteger`)  and a default value (`= Int`),

If a type `T` adopts the protocol and does not define `T.IndexDistance` otherwise then `T.IndexDistance` becomes a type alias for `Int`.
This is the case for many of the standard collection types
(such as `Array` or `String`), but not for all. For example

```
public struct AnyCollection<Element> : Collection
```

from the Swift standard library defines

```
    public typealias IndexDistance = IntMax
```

which you can verify with

```
let ac = AnyCollection([1, 2, 3])
let cnt = ac.count
print(type(of: cnt)) // Int64
```

You can also define your own collection type with a non-`Int` index distance if you like:

```
struct MyCollection : Collection {

    typealias IndexDistance = Int16
    var startIndex: Int { return  0 }
    var endIndex: Int { return  3 }

    subscript(position: Int) -> String {
        return "\(position)"
    }

    func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return i + 1
    }
}
```

Therefore, if you extend the concrete type `Array` then `count`
is an `Int`:

```
extension Array {
    func whatever() {
        let cnt = count // type is `Int`
    }
}
```

But in a protocol extension method

```
extension Collection {
    func whatever() {
        let cnt = count // some `SignedInteger`
    }
}
```

everything you know is that the type of `cnt` is *some* type adopting the 
`SignedInteger` protocol, but that need not be `Int`. One can still
work with the count, of course. Actually the compiler error in

```
    for index in 0...count { //  binary operator '...' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Self.IndexDistance'
```

is misleading. The integer literal `0` could be inferred as a 
`Collection.IndexDistance` from the context (because `SignedInteger`
conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`). But a range of `SignedInteger` is not a `Sequence`, and that's why it fails to compile.

So this would work, for example:

```
extension Collection {
    func whatever() {
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: count, by: 1) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

As of **Swift 4.1,** `IndexDistance` is no longer used, and 
the distance between collection indices is now always expressed as an `Int`, see

- [SE-0191 Eliminate IndexDistance from Collection](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0191-eliminate-indexdistance.md)

In particular the return type of `count` is `Int`. There is a type alias

```
typealias IndexDistance = Int
```

to make older code compile, but that is remarked deprecated and will be removed
in a future version of Swift.

Comment: does that `AnyCollection` compile for you? I'm getting 3 errors:  **type 'AnyCollection<Element>' does not conform to protocol 'Collection'** && **type 'AnyCollection<Element>' does not conform to protocol '_IndexableBase'** And upon calling it: **argument passed to call that takes no arguments**. Not really important but I also got a warning: **'IntMax' has been renamed to 'Int64'**

Comment: @Honey: No, it is not a typo: *If ... T ... does not define T.IndexDistance otherwise, then T.IndexDistance becomes a type alias for Int.* – And yes, that does compile for me.

Comment: @Honey: `struct AnyCollection` is an *existing* type from the Swift standard library, and what I pasted here (`public struct AnyCollection<Element> : Collection { ... }`) is an *extract* from its definition. You only need the example code following *"which you can verify with"* ...

Comment: @Honey: I have rewritten that part, to make it (hopefully) more clear.

Comment: `associatedtype IndexDistance: SignedInteger = Int` why at the protocol level it's not defaulted to `Int`? I guess it's by design just as you quoted _The actual type to use for that associated type isn’t specified until the protocol is adopted_ and since you can't adopt it at the protocol level of itself or within its extension then the type will still stay as `SignInteger`. Is that right? (You did quote it, but just didn't explicitly answer I _guess_). Also I think that key quote is missing from my own answer...making it somewhat futile

Comment: @Honey: I have problems to understand your problem :) Perhaps this: The default type for an associated type of a protocol applies only when an adopting type is *compiled.*

Comment: sorry. let me rephrase: About: `associatedtype IndexDistance: SignedInteger = Int`. Why doesn't collection just assume its of type `Int` and not `SignedInteger`. It's because of the quote from apple docs...ie it's by design. right?

Comment: @Honey: Yes, by design, perhaps to allow more flexibility in defining collection types. For Swift 4.1 they decided that this flexibility is not needed, and changed it as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer but being the OP I think these were all a vital prerequisite to my understanding. I did't know that:

- You can constrain the `associatedtype` of a protocol
- You can give the `associatedtype` a default type
- Conformance to a protocol's `associatedtype` *can* be done through using a `typealias`.
- Conformance to a protocol's `associatedtype` *can* be done through other ways as well ie though *defaulting*.
- **By design** the *default* type of the `associatedType` isn't triggered 'at the protocol level' ie it only gets constrained to its constrained Type. However once a class/struct adopts it...then and only then the default type is used. For more refer to [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49592061/5175709) above and Apple docs on [associatedtype](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189)
- There is a third way of conformance to protocol's `associatedtype`. Please see the link provided at the end. Basically, you can conform by defining the `associatedtype` *implicitly*
- Perhaps the most common way is to conform to a protocol with associated type through a generic constraint. See `SomeClass9`

---

### Three different Protocols

```
// associatedtype isn't constrained
protocol NotConstrained{
    associatedtype IndexDistance
}

// associatedtype is constrained
protocol Constrained{
    associatedtype IndexDistance: SignedInteger
}

// associatedtype is constrained and defaulted
protocol ConstrainedAndDefaulted{
    associatedtype IndexDistance: SignedInteger = Int
}
```

---

### Conformance to the protocols

```
// All Good
class someClass1: NotConstrained{
    typealias IndexDistance = Int
}

// All Good
class someClass2: NotConstrained{
    typealias IndexDistance = String // It works with String as well, since it wasn't constrained
}

// Not Good
class SomeClass3: NotConstrained{
    // error: type 'SomeClass3' does not conform to protocol 'NotConstrained'
    // doesn't work because we MUST have a typealias
}

// All Good
class SomeClass4: Constrained{
    typealias IndexDistance = Int16
}

// Not Good
class SomeClass5: Constrained{
    typealias IndexDistance = String
    // error: type 'SomeClass5' does not conform to protocol 'Constrained'
    // Obviously! Because String isn't of type 'SignedIngeter'
}

// Not Good
class SomeClass6: Constrained{
    // error: type 'SomeClass6' does not conform to protocol 'Constrained'        
}

// All Good
class SomeClass7: ConstrainedAndDefaulted{
    // NO ERROR, because the associatedtype has already defaulted
}

// All Good
class SomeClass8: ConstrainedAndDefaulted{
    typealias IndexDistance = Int64 // We changed the default from 'Int' to 'Int64'
    // Which is ok because 'Int64' is of type 'SignedInteger'
}

class SomeClass9<T> : NotConstrained {
    typealias IndexDistance = T
}
```

If you can understand why `class SomeClass8` works without errors then you've got your answer!

---

A very simple read can be found at [here](https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/generic-protocols-with-associated-type-7e2b6e079ee2). I really like how the post defines the difference between *implicit* and *explicit* conformance to the protocol's associatedtypes

### EDIT:

The [Understanding protocol associated types and their constraints](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/74/understanding-protocol-associated-types-and-their-constraints) tutorial is a fantastic read.

I will have to get back here and update my answer using the above tutorial. But until then refer to the link. It's really helpful.